# vscode code folding not showing closing brace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-folding

How do I make vscode editor show the closing braces of a folded code snippet
[image]

The image above represents what I have in my editor. However, I want to be able to see the closing braces.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The same issue was reported here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47240, I got a fix from that page

Here is the specific comment that resolves the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47240#issuecomment-379490218

Eyep, when using "editor.foldingStrategy": "auto" the block-closing bracket and everything after on the same line gets eaten up. Unlike it is with "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation". It can be extremely misleading, like for example in if else case:

[image]

VS. "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use this setting :
"editor.foldingStrategy": "**indentation**"
[image]